# Is there a need for GWT SafeHtml when using UiBinder?

Tags: java, html, gwt, xss

Let's say you have the following `MyPanel.ui.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <div>
        <span id="content">Some content</span>

        <gwt:RadioButton ...>
            ...
        </gwt:RadioButton>

        <!-- etc. -->
    </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And this "maps" to `MyPanel.java`:

```
public class MyPanel extends Composite {
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    // ...
}
```

Then are there any use cases where you would want/need to use SafeHtml or SafeHtmlBuilder, or is the "Safe*" API only needed when working with `HTML` objects and their underlying DOM structures?

If there are use cases where UiBinder-backed composites would need to use Safe*, perhaps a simple code example would help me connect the dots. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example where you should use SafeHTML in conjunction with UiBinder:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <gwt:HTMLPanel>
        <gwt:HTML ui:field="myHtml"/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

```java
public class MyPanel extends Composite {
    private HTML myHtml;
    // ...
}
```

Here you should use `myHtml.setHTML(SafeHTML)` <sup>[*]</sup>. The reason for that is, that this is the only place in the example, where *user provided content* might occur. User content can't occur in the UiBinder template itself (because that's static: fixed at compile time).

So the difference between requiring SafeHTML or not, is equivalent to the difference between trusting *user provided* content vs. trusting *developer provided* content.

<sup>[*] In your own example, you should use one of RadioButton's SafeHTML constructors</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Chris Lercher (+1) - I guess it's *starting* to make more sense. I think this is the root of my confusion: why is `HTML myHTML` considered "*user*-provided content", as opposed to, say, a RadioButton? Isn't it all just HTML at the end of the day? I think if you can help me understand the difference between user- and developer-provided content, I'll know how to identify which use cases are ripe for SafeHtml. Thanks again!

Comment: @orionTurtle: There's no basic difference between a RadioButton and an HTML widget - but I tried to simplify the example as much as possible (because RadioButton has many constructors etc.). Why is it regarded as user-provided content? It isn't. But it's the only place where user-provided content *might* occur.